# React-Native app crashes when put in Background

Tags: android, react-native

I am writing an application that renders a bunch of data through tables (react-native-table-component), and charts (react-native-chart-svg). The raw underlying data may weight approximately 150 kB.

When I put the app in background, it crashes on:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 852488 bytes
```

I guess it may be because my Activity (I only have one), uses `savedInstanceState`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to handle app links.
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
    _askForOverlayPermission();
}
```

And when I put my app in the background, it tries to save the state, which is too large. Currently, the state data contains like the id of each 'chunk of data', and then the data corresponding to this chunk (which weight way more). I was wondering if there was a way to say: "If the app is going to go in the background, drop all the data, just keep the ids, so it doesn't crash?

Thank you very much.

Comment: your bundle size is too large

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is not in your `onCreate` function. `onCreate` is basically, the lifecycle function which is called when you are initializing an `Activity` or starting an `Activity`. If you are getting the exception while your application goes into the background, then pay close attention to the `onPause` and `onDestroy` function. I guess these two are trying to pass some intents to other activities or services which is causing the error.

Hence, you may consider writing some code in your `onPause` method of your activity, which will save the ids in the `SharedPreferences` or in some database. And then when you are back again and resuming your application again, the `onResume` function will be called and retain your ids from the `SharedPreferences` or database (wherever you saved the data earlier).

To learn about how you can save the data in `SharedPreferences`, here is the [developer's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences). And of course, I would like to suggest you look into the [activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) too.

Comment: Thank you very much, this doc is very useful! I was hoping to avoid all this Android-specific stuff by using React-Native but apparently I was wrong. Just another question though: it appears that my app is not crashing anymore, after adding:

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.clear();
    }

to my activity, do you know why it would work?

Comment: You are clearing the instances that you have saved. Looks like you are not saving anything.

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't really understand. How can the app keep its state (I do not have to login again, or re-render data), if it's not saving anything?